# Using shutdown() for a UDP socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

what is  the effect of "shutdown" function on a udp socket?

```
int shutdown(int socket, int how);
```

Comment: Did you test it to see for yourself?

Comment: The shutdown function will disable receiving or sending or both on ANY kind of socket.. Any data received or sent during that time will be queued (UDP) or connection will be reset (TCP).

Comment: It is legal but it does exactly nothing with a UDP socket, except possibly inhibit receiving if you shutdown the input. It isn't necessary in your original code: in fact `shutdown()` before `close()` is only necessary in any situation when there are inherited sockets.

Comment: @Brandon I cannot understand your comment. Leaving TCP aside, *all* data sent via UDP is queued. `shutdown()` doesn't enable it in any way.

Comment: Hmm @user207421; I made the mistake of assuming it was the same as on Windows :S https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-shutdown ."For TCP sockets, if there is still data queued on the socket waiting to be received, or data arrives subsequently, the connection is reset, since the data cannot be delivered to the user. For UDP sockets, incoming datagrams are accepted and queued. In no case will an ICMP error packet be generated."  Can't see how these posix functions are always implemented differently across these platforms -_-

Comment: @Brandon Input is always queued. The point is that in Windows, shutdown for input doesn't *stop* it being queued, when arguably it should.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `shutdown()` on a UDP socket does nothing on the wire, and only affects the state of the socket object.

Looking at the kernel:

- `__sys_shutdown()` [calls `sock->ops->shutdown()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.5/net/socket.c#L2193) on the socket object. `ops` is a `struct proto_ops`.
- For IPv4 (`AF_INET`), [`inet_stream_ops.shutdown`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.5/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L996) is set to [`inet_shutdown`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.5/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L847).
- `inet_shutdown` is very TCP-oriented, and kind of screwy. However, it [checks `sk->sk_prot->shutdown` and calls it if it is non-NULL](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.5/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L878-L879).
- `sk_prot` [points to](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.5/include/net/sock.h#L181) a `struct proto`:

  - For TCP, we can see that `struct proto tcp_prot` [defines a `.shutdown`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.5/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L2581) operation (`tcp_shutdown`)
  - However the UDP `struct proto udp_prot` [does not define `.shutdown`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.5/net/ipv4/udp.c#L2773)